# UINavigationBar back button does not appear

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uibuttonbaritem

I have a navigationBar, with a UIImage on it's title, like this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_logo.png"]];
```

When i select a row, the "back" button does not appear. Why?

I have the exact same code on other's viewControllers, and it appears.
I don't understand why...

Thanks,

RL

Comment: does it appear when you set navigationItem.title?

Comment: If the navigationItem.title is a text, then the back button appears when I push another viewcontroller...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The back button won't appear unless you've set `self.navigationItem.title` or 'self.title' in the previous view controller on the stack (parent VC) or explicitly created a `UIBarButtonItem` and set it to `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in the previous view controller on the stack (parent VC).

Comment: @benwong Hi, the title is set like this: detailViewController.title=NSLocalizedString(@"Info", @"info");

Comment: The title of the view controller is different from the title of the view controller navigation item.

Comment: @benwong Hi. Parent VC: self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_logo.png"]];
Child VC (called in Partent VC didSelectRow... method): chamadasDetalhe.title=NSLocalizedString(@"Info", @"info");
when the child is pushed, there's no back button...

Comment: Ok. I just tested a couple of things myself. self.title works as well.

Comment: That would be assuming too much. The titleView doesn't have to be an UIImageView. If it was a UISegmentedControl for example, it wouldn't make much sense to make that into a back button.

Answer (score 0):

did you push the new view through the navigation stack?

like:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToPush animated:YES];`

Comment: Hi, yes. They are all with the same kind of code: [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: I don't know what's happening. I have a TabBarController, with 4 Tabs. All work the same way. Only in the first one that occurs... :-(

Comment: how did you create the tab bar items?

Comment: with IB. It works if use text in the title. With an image, in the first tabBarVC does not work in child viewcontrollers...